# Getting an alignment's excluded positions from a Nexus file

Tags: biopython

I can successfully use BioPython's AlignIO module to read a Nexus file and generate a list of sequences and IDs. Nexus files generated by Mesquite and other programs may define a [set of excluded positions](http://hydrodictyon.eeb.uconn.edu/eebedia/index.php/Phylogenetics%3a_NEXUS_Format#Assumptions_block) (called the exset) which are to be ignored or filtered out further down the line. Does Biopython provide a way to parse the exset from a nexus file? (Ideally into a list of integers). I could not find a mention in the documentation. Right now I've written my own function which is a little clunky and might be too dependent on the particular nexus files I've been testing with.

Answer (score 0):

Biopython has limited support for this, if any. But the data you are looking for is in the Nexus object:

```
from Bio.Nexus import Nexus

# I'm using the sample file from
# http://paup.csit.fsu.edu/data/primate-mtDNA-interleaved.nex
nex = Nexus.Nexus(input="sample.nex")

for block in nex.unknown_blocks:
    if block.title == "assumptions":
        for assumption in block.commandlines[0]:
            if assumption.startswith("exset"):
                print assumption
```

Output:

```
exset coding = noncoding
exset noncoding = coding
```

So the parser loads the "assumptions" block into the unknown_blocks. There you can search for the block called "assumptions" and manually parse the lines . The commandlines contains a list with lists, so here I extracted the very first one. It seems easy to create your own dedicated parser, just for the lines starting with "exset".